# jQuery events not working when views AJAX is enabled with exposed filter

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal-7, view, drupal-exposed-filter

I have a Drupal 7 website. I am using Responsive Dropdown Menus module to main responsive menu. It is working fine on all the pages expect 2-3 pages.

Then after digging more, I realized it does not work on the page I have views block with exposed filter functionality on and AJAX on. I guess there is some interference between views AJAX and jQuery not working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I could resolve this issue by updating to the latest stable version of views. Just in case, you are struggling with same issue, please update to latest version of views module.